# Compute Percentage and Count document using MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to create a query where it is computing the total amount, counting number of transaction and also computing how many % is the total amount from the Grand Total. Sample document is provided below and the expected output.

Sample Documents

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84b4"),
    "orders": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b84be"),
        "amount": 2000
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("606557900dd9a34bcc0faf90"),
        "amount": 1500
      }
    ],
    "orderdate": "2021-08-29T00:00:00.000Z",
    "orderarea": "East Branch"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60dc27ac54b7c46bfa1b75ge2"),
    "orders": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("6068016a7feeb34a6013e687"),
        "amount": 3000
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60dca0ea4550fd32beb5ad38"),
        "amount": 5000
      }
    ],
    "orderdate": "2021-08-30T00:00:00.000Z",
    "orderarea": "West Branch"
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60dc9ecf188cf96dd6f58c45"),
    "orders": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60dca0ea4550fd32beb5ad3a"),
        "amount": 4500
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("60dcac6d51b2bd1e009d7bdc"),
        "amount": 6000
      }
    ],
    "orderdate": "2021-08-31T00:00:00.000Z",
    "orderarea": "East Branch"
  }
]
```

Output

```
{"East Branch": 14000, "countoftransaction": 4, "amountpercentage": 63.63%},
{"West Branch": 8000, "countoftransaction": 2, "amountpercentage": 36.36%}
```

The percentage should compute how many percentage it is from the grand total amount of East branch and West Branch which is 22,000.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar solution can be:

- First `$unwind` `orders` to deconstructs the array.
- Using `$facet` it will comput "two ways".
- In one way `$group` to get total value for each area
- In the oter way `$group` to get all amounts.
- Then get the first position (`$facet` output an array) and `$unwind` again.
- And last stages is to get the final representation. I've added `$concat` to output the percent as string with `%`

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$unwind": "$orders"
},
{
  "$facet": {
    "data": [
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": "$orderarea",
          "total": {
            "$sum": "$orders.amount"
          },
          "countoftransaction": {
            "$sum": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "totalAmount": [
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": null,
          "totalAmount": {
            "$sum": "$orders.amount"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "data": 1,
    "totalAmount": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        "$totalAmount",
        0
      ]
    }
  }
},
{
  "$unwind": "$data"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "totalAmount": "$totalAmount.totalAmount"
  }
},
{
  "$project": {
    "id": "$data._id",
    "countoftransaction": 1,
    "total": "$data.total",
    "amountpercentage": {
      "$concat": [
        {
          "$toString": {
            "$round": [
              {
                "$multiply": [
                  {
                    "$divide": [
                      "$data.total",
                      "$totalAmount"
                    ]
                  },
                  100
                ]
              },
              2
            ]
          }
        },
        "%"
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yy28CcW5qqJ)

Note that the final result is like this:

```json
[
  {
    "amountpercentage": "36.36%",
    "id": "West Branch",
    "total": 8000
  },
  {
    "amountpercentage": "63.64%",
    "id": "East Branch",
    "total": 14000
  }
]
```

There is no an easy way to get values as keys. Also if you prefer you can use [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Md8XYnKwp5y) which output result as:

```
[
  {
    "East Branch": {
      "amountpercentage": "63.64%",
      "countoftransaction": 4,
      "total": 14000
    }
  },
  {
    "West Branch": {
      "amountpercentage": "36.36%",
      "countoftransaction": 2,
      "total": 8000
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Just and additional question if every I will put a "countpercentage", Can i include it inside TotalAmount in facet or create another computation there?

Answer (score 1):

use this aggregation , but in mongo we couldn't create dynamic field name `"East Branch": 14000`

this is aggregation

```
[
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$orders'
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': None, 
            'total': {
                '$sum': '$orders.amount'
            }, 
            'orig': {
                '$push': '$$ROOT'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$orig'
        }
    }, {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$orig.orderarea', 
            'countoftransaction': {
                '$sum': 1
            }, 
            'ff': {
                '$sum': '$orig.orders.amount'
            }, 
            'dd': {
                '$addToSet': '$total'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$addFields': {
            'total': {
                '$first': '$dd'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            'amountpercentage': {
                '$round': [
                    {
                        '$multiply': [
                            {
                                '$divide': [
                                    '$ff', '$total'
                                ]
                            }, 100
                        ]
                    }, 2
                ]
            }, 
            'countoftransaction': 1, 
            'amount': '$ff'
        }
    }
]
```

and the result is like this :

```
[
{_id:"West Branch",countoftransaction:2,amountpercentage:36.36,amount:8000},
{_id:"Eest Branch",countoftransaction:4,amountpercentage:63.64,amount:14000}
]
```